# Emberjs display data after promise gets fulfilled?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am a bit conceptually confused about how this works.

The user enters data on the form, presses next. The controller 's `nextStep` action fires and I ask the model to get data from the server. When the data arrives, I transition to the results route. At that point, I have the route store the previous model on a variable on the controller. Then I want to iterate through the data on the template.

The problem is that nothing shows up.

This is what I have (in the appropriate files):

```
//Step 1 Controller (partial - nextStep action)
var businessmatch = this.store.find('businessmatch', {businessname: businessname, phonenumber: phonenumber, zipcode: zipcode})
    .then(function (result) {
         // The model has data at this point
         controller.transitionToRoute('step2');
    });


// step2 Router
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('businessmatches', this.store.find('businessmatch'));
    }
});

// Step2 template (partial)
        {{#each businessmatches}}
            {{businessname}}
        {{/each}}

// Model
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Businessmatch = DS.Model.extend({
    businessname: DS.attr('string'),
    phonenumber: DS.attr('string'),
    address: DS.attr('string'),
    pageurl: DS.attr('string'),
    thubmurl: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Businessmatch;

// Sample response from server
{
   "businessmatches":[
      {
         "businessname":"El Farolito",
         "pageurl":"/biz/el-farolito-san-francisco-2",
         "thumburl":"/bphoto/ohpxQWg-hB9Sb27HkVg-yQ/90s.jpg",
         "address":"780 El Camino RealMillbrae, CA 94030",
         "phonenumber":"(650) 583-0487",
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "businessname":"El Farolito",
         "pageurl":"/biz/el-farolito-san-francisco-4",
         "thumburl":"/photo/AW76YTovuu9YsO69_BcLKQ/30s.jpg",
         "address":"2779 Mission StSan Francisco, CA 94110",
         "phonenumber":"(415) 824-7877",
         "id":2
      },
      {
         "businessname":"El Farolito",
         "pageurl":"/biz/el-farolito-san-francisco",
         "thumburl":"/bphoto/LgTOTIicRY6XArigmPhBpw/90s.jpg",
         "address":"2950 24th StSan Francisco, CA 94110",
         "phonenumber":"(415) 641-0758",
         "id":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tstirrat is correct, the `store.all()` method [immediately returns an array of cached records](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L864), while the `store.find()` method [returns a promise of fetched records](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L463).

Is there a specific reason you aren't using the model hooks in your route? They are promise aware, and will wait for your `store.find()` to resolve then pass the model on to your setupController. You can then reference the previous models with `modelFor('step1')` or just use `store.all()` again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! By model hook, you mean `model: function() {return this.store.find('businessmatch')}`? I assumed that `setupController` and this were equivalent with the only difference being that in the latter I could specify the property 's name while one the former it would be `model`. So much for making assumptions :| For the record, I tested `all()` more than once in the case where the transition was set outside the promise 's`then` section and the template updated when the data was received. `RecordArray` has an `update` method so perhaps some magic happens there?

Comment: Yes, routes have `beforeModel`, `model`, and `afterModel` as described in the [Ember guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/). `setupController` happens immediately after `afterModel`, and does not wait for promises to resolve before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, if I change

`controller.set('businessmatches', this.store.find('businessmatch'));`

to

`controller.set('businessmatches', this.store.all('businessmatch'));`
it works as expected.

Would be interested to know why though, if anyone can explain.

Comment: `this.store.all('businessmatch')` is a a sync operation. It returns only cached copies already present in the store. If you want it to actually query the api, you'd need to use it like a promise: `this.store.find('businessmatch').then(function (results) { // set controller property here })`

Comment: @tstirrat The thing is, if I do the `transitionToRoute` without waiting for the promise to get fulfilled (and use `.all()`), the page will load empty and the values will get filled later. I expected the same would happen with `find()`, but it doesn't.